# Normal but not Hausdorff, satisfying Urysohn lemma

Tags: general-topology

I know that, in general, normal space may not be Hausdorff.

Indiscrete topolgy with more than one point is one of the examples.

Then, if space satisfy urysohn's lemma (separate closed sets by continuous functions), then sould it be Hausforff?

Or is there any example that normal, not Hausdorff, satisfying Urysohn's lemma?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the indiscrete topology it holds true that disjoint closed sets can be separated by continuous functions. Due to a lack of closed sets, the constant functions returning 0 and 1 respectively suffice. Basically, any separation property only taking about closed sets as starting point will hold for the indiscrete topology. Thus, we would usually include the $T_1$-axiom, which ensures enough closed sets for those properties to be meaningful.

Comment: I think empty set is closed set, and it maps to empty set, so separation by function does not hold

Comment: @KimSeongHyeon  If you want to separate $\emptyset$ from $X$ by a continuous function, then the constant function returning $1$ works.